# onRequest vs Callable Cloud function

Tags: python, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I just have few questions that I couldn't derive an answer from the docs. In my app, I want to have a cloud function that can only get called if a user is authenticated. I have written a http onRequest function in python that works only if the function is made public. As long as I am passing the user's id token into the function and verifying it with the admin sdk is there anything wrong with that?

Also, would there be any benefit to rewritting it in node and using a callable cloud function instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, it seems to nothing wrong with your approach but passing tokens and verifying them may be prone to developer errors and causes harder maintainability.

Callable functions have the following benefits:

- You can enable **App Check** to add extra layer of security to ensure your functions are called from your app. [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check#how_strong_is_the_security_provided_by) says: *Using App Check does not guarantee the elimination of all abuse, but by integrating with App Check, you are taking an important step towards abuse protection for your backend resources.*
- Callable function paramaters natively includes UserRecord object and many more on context parameter. Meaning that you can get information of the user who invoked the function easily. [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) says: *With callables, Firebase Authentication tokens, FCM tokens, and App Check tokens, when available, are automatically included in requests.*